# Ansible - Difference Between Tags and Roles

Tags: ansible

Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754594/whats-the-difference-between-roles-and-tasks-and-tags-in-ansible), but I know what a task is and cannot find much differentiation between tags and roles.

It seems to me, that tags may be a simpler version of roles, with their only use being accessible via the `--tags` and `--skip-tags` CLI parameters.

Roles on the other hand, are used for "automatically loading" things like tasks and variables?

Please, explain the benefits to using roles, because it seems to me like roles require you to have different yaml files for the different parts (tasks, vars, etc) which I could accomplish with less code using the `include` and `tags`
directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags and roles are different things.

**Roles** are used to aggregate some group of tasks which do certain thing, e.g. one role can contain tasks that install some service and a second role tasks to configure this service.

Each role has its own directory structure:

```
site.yml
webservers.yml
fooservers.yml
roles/
   common/
     tasks/
     handlers/
     files/
     templates/
     vars/
     defaults/
     meta/
   webservers/
     tasks/
     defaults/
     meta/
```

So for each role you can define e.g. variables, templates, tasks etc. It makes Ansible scripts clear and transparent. Another advantage is that you can reuse roles in different playbooks.

So instead of defining all tasks in a single playbook, which can become a little messy if playbook contained many tasks:

```
- name: Install nginx and mysql
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Install nginx
      ...
    - name: Configure nginx
      ...
    - name: Install mysql
      ...
    - name: Configure mysql
      ...
```

You can create roles and include them:

```
- name: Install nginx and mysql
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  roles:
    - nginx
    - mysql
```

I suggest to take a look at the [examples where roles are used](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/).

**Tags** are used while running `ansible-playbook` command to indicate which tasks should be executed.

> If you have a large playbook it may become useful to be able to run a specific part of the configuration without running the whole playbook.

So it is possible to tag some roles/tasks and run/skip only them while executing playbook.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because you provided an example. Something like the directory structure for roles is what I was hoping for to draw the distinction. Especially the examples on GitHub, I didn't know about those and they were exactly what I needed to understand their usefulness.

Answer (score 5):

> It seems to me, that tags may be a simpler version of roles.

Sorry, but this is completely wrong.

Roles are self-contained reusable units (with own variables, tasks, handlers and even plugins and modules!). You can use them in multiple playbooks and/or plays in your project. You can share them between multiple projects. You can use role dependencies. You can redistribute them via external resources (e.g. Ansible Galaxy). For example, role `nginx` to install and configure nginx server, and role `apache` for apache server.

Tags are used to make it possible to execute only specific tasks in your project. You can mark plays/roles/tasks with tags. For example, tag `config` to mark only configuration-related tasks inside our `nginx` and `apache` role. So later you can execute `ansible-playbook -t config site.yml` to run configuration only tasks for all type of servers instead of whole playbook.

Comment: That's a better summary than I could have gotten from reading the docs 3 more times, thank you. I suppose the only thing I could ask for now would be an example that makes more sense than what's shown on the docs; but you've answered my question so I'll leave it up to you if you want to provide one or not.

Comment: Since you and kzygmans answered at the same time, I gave him the answer for providing an example in addition to a link of many examples.